# Using Tweepy to print tweets just from your friends

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been trying to figure out Tweepy for the last 3 hours and I'm still stuck. 
I would like to be able to get all my friend's tweets for the period between Sept and Oct 2014, and have it be filtered by the top 10 number of retweets.

I'm only vaguely familiar with StreamListener, however, I think this does a list of tweets that are real time. I was wondering if I could go back last month and grab out those tweets from my friends. Can this be done through Tweepy? This is the code I have now.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

import csv

ckey = 'xyz'
csecret = 'xyz'
atoken = 'xyz'
asecret = 'xyz'

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, a secret)

class Listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self,data):
        print data
        return True
    def on_error(self,status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
tiwtterStream = Stream(aut, Listener())

users = [123456, 7890019, 9919038] # this is the list of friends I would like to output
twitterStream.filter(users, since=09-01-2014, until = 10-01-2014)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that `StreamListener` returns real-time tweets. To get past tweets from specific users, you need to use tweepy's API wrapper--`tweepy.API`.  An example, which would replace from your `Listener` class on down:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweetlist = api.user_timeline(id=123456)
```

This returns a list of up to 20 `status` objects. You can mess with the [parameters](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.user_timeline) to get more results, probably `count` and `since` will be helpful for your implementation. I think the most you can ask for with a single `count` is [200 tweets](https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496).

P.S. Not a major issue but you authenticate twice in your code which is not necessary.